# How to get multiple instances of mongodb-compass to run side-by-side

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and mongodb 4.0.3 community, and mongodb-compass 1.15.4 - trying to have two instances of mongodb-compass running side-by-side.  When I double-click my launcher icon it opens the first instance of mongodb-compass.  When I double-click my launcher the second time it sets focus on the current running instance of mongodb-compass but does not open a second instance.

I have tried to invoke using the command line and again the focus is set to the current running instance.

How do I start another instance of mongodb-compass to run side-by-side with the first instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mongo Compass, click the "Connect" menu and select "Connect To".  It will open another instance for you.

Comment: Yeah I was actually trying the same as you when I first started using it.  I think it's common to expect a new instance when you click the launcher.